# in UIScrollView setContentSize working only one

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

In my application, I have some information in UIScrollView.
Content in UIScrollView can be changed by filter.

First time, when ViewController loads, I put all items in ScrollView, and everything working perfect.
If user wants to apply some filter to ScrollView, I remove all old items, make new, and set a new setContentSize:

```
- (void) displayCars:(NSMutableArray*)cars {
    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [scrollView subviews];
    for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) [v removeFromSuperview];

    int itemHeight = 100;
    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = cars.count * itemHeight;
    if (scrollViewHeight < scrollView.frame.size.height) scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollViewHeight)];

    for (int i=0; i < cars.count; i++) {
        VitoCarsAdv * adv = [cars objectAtIndex:i];

        VIOneCar *carView = [[VIOneCar alloc] init];
        [carView setFrame:CGRectMake (0, (i * itemHeight), scrollView.frame.size.width, itemHeight)];
        [carView setData:adv];

        [scrollView addSubview:carView];
    }
}
```

ScrollView is filling up by new items, but the contentSize is the same, like in previous situation, where was all items inside. Actually, it is not changed second time.

It is not comfortable behaviour for user, can somebody advice me, where I should look?

Please note, that Autolayout is swithed off for this View Controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right I think you just mistyped some code. Here's what you wrote:

```
int itemHeight = 100;
CGFloat scrollViewHeight = cars.count * itemHeight;
if (scrollViewHeight < scrollView.frame.size.height) {
     scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
}
```

With that code, the scrollViewHeight will never shrink to a smaller size. You are setting a minimum size of whatever the scrollView.frame.size.height currently is. Is that your intended function? If not, it you should just remove the if statement leaving you with:

```
CGFloat scrollViewHeight = cars.count * itemHeight;
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollViewHeight)];
```

Comment: My code is correct. contentSize shouldn't be less, than scrollView frame.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to resize the actual frame of the scrollview or are you trying to adjust the contentSize so you can scroll through your cars?

Comment: I changing only contentSize

Comment: Then the content size MUST be **BIGGER** than the scrollView so that you can scroll through all the items. Try my code and take out the "if statement" I am certain it will work.